# Would like to get some feedback about a probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm just working on this past exam paper question and would like to know if I'm doing everything correctly. Here is the question;

An experiment consists of three fair, different coloured dice being rolled (the dice are 6-sided
and the sides show numbers 1, . . . , 6). Let A be the event that none of the dice shows
numbers 1 and 2, and let B be the event that all dice show an odd number.

(a) What is the probability of A?

(b) What is the probability of B?

(c) What is the probability of A ∩ B?

(d) Are the events A and B independent? (You must justify your answer!)

I have answered the question and would like your feedback;

a) P(A) = 4/6 = 2/3
So because there are three dice = 2/3 * 2/3 * 2/3 = 8/27

b) P(B) = 3/6 = 1/2
So because there are three dices = ½ * ½* ½ =1/8

c) P(A ∩ B) = 2/6 =1/3
So because there are three dices = 1/3 * 1/3* 1/3* = 1/27

d) The events are not independent as P(A and B) do not equal to P(A)P(B), because the outcomes of one, impact the other.

Comment: Your notation is eccentric.  You write $P(A)=\frac 23$ but then you compute a different value for it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, it looks like you compute $P(A\cap B)=\frac 1{27}$ which really does look like the product of the values you get for $P(A),P(B)$ ($\frac 8{27}$ and $\frac 18$ respectively).  Please edit your post for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part **(d)** Note that the set $\{1,2\}$ includes one odd and one even element.  So, $P(A \vert B)=P(A)$.  If you follow the definition $$P(A \cap B)=P(A \vert B) P(B)=P(A)P(B)$$